# How to implement custom action in testcafe using typescript?

Tags: typescript, testcafe

I'm trying to implement custom action but with no luck. I'm getting an error telling me that my custom action is not a function when running test using new custom action.

```
TypeError: testcafe_1.t.customActions.selectFromDropdown is not a function
```

But from the beginning. I've created definitions.d.ts file containing definition for custom action:

```
//definitions.d.ts
import 'testcafe';
declare global {
    interface CustomActions {
        selectFromDropdown: (dropdownSelector: Selector) => TestControllerPromise
    }
}
```

After that, I've added function body to .testcaferc.ts file:

```
//.testcaferc.ts
let os = require("os");
import { Selector, ClientFunction, Role, t } from 'testcafe';

module.exports = {
    browsers: ["chrome"],
    src: ["tests/**/*.js", "tests/**/*.feature", "definitions.d.ts", "tests"],
    hostname: "localhost",
    customActions: {
        async selectFromDropdown(dropdownSelector: Selector) {
            await this.click(dropdownSelector);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm using custom action like this:

```
await t.customActions.selectFromDropdown(Selector('#dropdownSelector'));
```

Test looks like this (I've simplified it, but error remains the same). I'm opening a page using beforeEach and then I want to use custom action:

```
//01_basic.ts

import { Selector, ClientFunction, t } from 'testcafe';
import { startPage } from '../../../pages/start-page';


const startSettings = startPage.getStartSettings();

fixture('11-01 - Customercard SMS, functionality')
    .beforeEach(async () => {
        await startPage.selectPage(startPage.customerCardPageButton);   
    });

test('00 - Custom action click', async (t) => {
   t.customActions.selectFromDropdown(Selector('#dropdownSelector'));
})
```

I'm running a test using npx:

```
npx testcafe chrome .\tests\01_basic.ts --test "00 - Custom action click"
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I bet there will be much. I do not have much experience with testcafe and ts.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce the issue. Please share your test and describe how you run it.

Comment: I've updated a question with those details

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is not sufficient. As far as I can see, you use the TestCafe config file with the `ts` extension. But TestCafe doesn't support it by default. Thus, I suppose that you do some preliminary actions and then compile your config via TypeScript. Would you please clarify if my assumption is correct? Please also share a simple example that can be reproduced without effort. In addition, specify the NodeJS and TestCafe versions you're using.

Comment: I've uploaded basic code to the github public repo. This should help

https://github.com/rosinski90/testcafe_custom_action

I'm running test by "npx testcafe chrome .\tests\01_basic.ts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a TestCafe configuration file with the `*.ts` extension. TestCafe support only `*.js`, `*.cjs`, and `*json` extensions for a configuration file. See: [Configuration File](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file).

If you still want to use this extension for the configuration file, pre-compile it before running tests. Also, keep in mind that TestCafe reads the configuration file only with the `.testcaferc` name and only from the repository root. In other cases, you need to manually set a path to the configuration file by specifying the [`--config-file`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--config-file-path) option.

Comment: Converting .testcaferc config file to .js helped. Thank you!